# Is there such a thing as HeaderMatch for apache?

Tags: apache2

I am "managing" some file's version by setting their last modified date manually when serving them with apache, like so

```
<Directory />
    (...)
    Header set Last-modified "Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT"
    (...)
</Directory>
```

This already works fine.

If the client honors the cache standard, it should send me the `If-Modified-Since` header in the next request, where I'd return 304 instead of 200.

Is there any way to accomplish the following without too much hassle? (I don't need fancy processing or anything, the most hardcoded way will work ok for me)

I need something like this (it's obviously in pseudo code):

```
<HeaderMatch If-Modified-Since>
    (...)
    If Equals "Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT"
        Header set Code 304
    Else
        // Process Directory section
</HeaderMatch>
```

Any ideas/workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was easy.

Using mod_rewrite, I ended up with this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:if-modified-since} "Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT" [NC]
RewriteRule .* . [R=304,L]
```